# getting row values in dynamically constructed html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

[image]I am constructing a dynamic table inside the servlet with the checkbox and i given the id for the check box,and now am trying to get a selected check box row values in a button click and am getting wrong values, if i selected the check box for a 4th row value means the alert displaying the 2nd row value, below i have given my servlet and jquery code,
  see the output image i have selected  260 number row but the alert is showing 257 this is the my problem.
Servlet code,

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        PreparedStatement distscenarioName = null;
        PreparedStatement minscenariId = null;
        PreparedStatement testcaseName = null;
        String scenari_name = null; 
        Connection connection=DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
        distscenarioName=connection.prepareStatement("select distinct scenario_name from scenario");
        ResultSet rs=distscenarioName.executeQuery();
        out.println("<tr><td><b>");
        out.println("Scenario Name:");
        out.println("</b></td><td><b>");
        out.println("Testcase ID:");
        out.println("</b></td><td><b>");
        out.println("Testcase Name:");
        out.println("</b></td><td><b>");
        out.println("Testcase Description:");
        out.println("</b></td><td><b>");
        out.println("Action:");
        out.println("</b></td></tr>");
        int i=0;
        while(rs.next()){
            scenari_name=rs.getString("scenario_name");
            minscenariId=connection.prepareStatement("select min(scenario_id) from scenario where scenario_name =?");
            minscenariId.setString(1, scenari_name);
            ResultSet rss=minscenariId.executeQuery();              
            if(rss.next()){
                testcaseName=connection.prepareStatement("select tc_id,tc_desc,tc_name from testcase where scenario_id=?");
                testcaseName.setInt(1,rss.getInt("min(scenario_id)"));
                ResultSet testcaseExe=testcaseName.executeQuery();  
                out.println("<tr><td><h4>");
                out.println(scenari_name);
                out.println("</td></h4><td></td><td></td><td></td><td><input type=checkbox class='btnChckBox'></td></tr>");                 
                while(testcaseExe.next()){                      
                    out.println("<tr><td>");
                    out.println("<td id='testCaseId"+i+"'>");
                    out.println(testcaseExe.getInt(1));
                    out.println("</td>");
                    out.println("</td><td id='testCaseName"+i+"'>");
                    out.println(testcaseExe.getString("tc_name"));
                    out.println("</td><td>");
                    out.println(testcaseExe.getString("tc_desc"));
                    out.println("</td><td>");
                    out.println("<input type=checkbox class='btnChckBox' id='action"+i+"'>");
                    out.println("</td></tr>");
                    i++;
                }

                //out.println("<input type='hidden' id='gridSize' value='"+i+"'>");

            }
        }
```

and my jquery code is

```
$('#StartExec').click(function() {
                     $('#testcaseTable tr').each(function(i) {
                            var tcID = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                            var tcName = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                            var cellvalues = this.cells[4].innerHTML;
                            if($('#action'+i).prop('checked')){
                                 alert('Inside if tc ID::::::::'+tcID);
                                    alert('inside if tc name::::::'+tcName);
                            }

                        });
                });
```

Comment: What is StartExec, I did not find it in the servlet code

Comment: tats one button id, for a button click event am i have reading the table row values for a button click.

by using the following ajax call am constructing a table

$.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : "./ScenarioTCExecutionPage",
       success : function(result) {
        /* alert("Length"+result.toString().length); *//*
                     * alert("length"+result.length());
                     */
        $("#testcaseTable").html(result);        
        $("#testcaseTable").show();}
      });

Comment: Can you provide us with a jsfiddle demo with dummy data, so we can help you better.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have multiple buttons of same id. Secondly, since you are constructing it dynamically, its better bind the handler in this way:     $('document').on('click','#StartExec',function(){
    //Your code here
    });

Comment: tat click is not a problem yaar, if i selected the 3 rd row check box the alert is displaying first row values.

Comment: dear @kamalesh please see the image i have uploaded

Comment: Can you provide your html and js code in jsfiddle?

Comment: @kamalesh really thanks kamalesh, one of our friend Mukesh given the solution for me,,thanks for a support ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please set a id of tr** and **checkbox** like:

**see ** lines :**

```
while(testcaseExe.next()){    

                    **out.println("<tr id="+testcaseExe.getInt(1)+"><td>");**

                    out.println("<td id='testCaseId"+i+"'>");
                    out.println(testcaseExe.getInt(1));
                    out.println("</td>");
                    out.println("</td><td id='testCaseName"+i+"'>");
                    out.println(testcaseExe.getString("tc_name"));
                    out.println("</td><td>");
                    out.println(testcaseExe.getString("tc_desc"));
                    out.println("</td><td>");
                    **out.println("<input type=checkbox class='btnChckBox' id='action"+testcaseExe.getInt(1)+"'>");**
                    out.println("</td></tr>");
                    i++;
                }
```

and Your jquery code is

```
$('#StartExec').click(function() {
                     $('#testcaseTable tr').each(function(i) {
                               if($('#action'+this.id).prop('checked')){
                                 alert('Inside if tc ID::::::::'+tcID);
                                    alert('inside if tc name::::::'+tcName);
                            }

                        });
                });
```

Comment: Dear @Mukesh Dabhi great help in a timely manner bro, Really thanks a lot u saved me...